# SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose Doesn't Close

Tags: modal-dialog

I'm using a ModalDialog and have a strange issue.

On a button click server side in my popup, I've this line:

```
this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "PopupScript", "popData = '" + checkedValue + "';SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(1, popData);", true);
```

Here is what I have in the parent:

```
LiteralControl lc = new LiteralControl();
lc.Text = @"
    <script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
        function ShowDialog(){
            var modalDialog;
            var options = {
                title: 'Vue détaillée',
                allowMaximize: true,
                showClose: true,
                url:'/_Layouts/Molnlycke.search/PopupSelUrl.aspx',
                dialogReturnValueCallback: onPopUpCloseCallBackWithData
            }; 
            modalDialog = SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options); 
        }
        function onPopUpCloseCallBackWithData(result, returnValue){
            document.getElementById('"+ tbUrl.ClientID +"').value = returnValue;
        }
    </script>";

this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "JS", lc.Text);
```

and my button:

```
<asp:Button ID="btSelUrl" runat="server" OnClientClick="ShowDialog()" Text="Open popup"/>
```

I correctly receive the value in the parent windows, but it doesn't close the popup.

If I click a second time, it closes the popup.

Do you know what the mistake is?

Comment: i removed the onclientclick="showdialog()" and place in page_load: btSelUrl.Attributes["onclick"] = "ShowDialog();return false;";
now it seems working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like your timing is getting crossed. Here is a full working example of using the modal dialog, and passing data to and from the parent page:

In the parent page mark up:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showModal() {
        var options = {
            url: '/web/_layouts/Dialog/TestModal.aspx',
            title: 'Hello World',
            allowMaximize: false,
            dialogReturnValueCallback: modalClosed,
            args: {
                arg1: $('#<%= tbArg1.ClientID %>').val(),
                arg2: $('#<%= tbArg2.ClientID %>').val()
            }
        };
        SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
    }
    function modalClosesd(result, args) {
        if (result == SP.UI.DialogResult.OK) {
            $('#<%= tbArg1.ClientID %>').val(args.arg1);
            $('#<%= tbArg2.ClientID %>').val(args.arg2);
        }
    }
</script>
```

In your modal dialog markup:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function cancelClicked() {
        SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(SP.UI.DialogResult.Cancel, null);
    }
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {
        var args = SP.UI.ModalDialog.get_childDialog().get_args();
        if (!isNullOrEmpty(args.arg1)) {
            $('#<%= tbArg1.ClientID %>').val(args.arg1);
        }
        if (!isNullOrEmpty(args.arg2)) {
            $('#<%= tbArg2.ClientID %>').val(args.arg2);
        }
    }, "SP.UI.Dialog.js");
</script>
```

The server side Click event handler:

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "saveSuccess",
        @"<script type='text/javascript'>
            ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(
                function() {
                    var args = {
                        arg1: '" + tbArg1.Text + @"',
                        arg2: '" + tbArg2.Text + @"'
                    };
                    SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK, args);
                }, 'SP.UI.Dialog.js');
        </script>");
}
```

The `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded()` function will cause the page to wait to fire the delegate passed to it until after the SharePoint 'SP.UI.Dialog.js' javascript file (containing the `SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose` function) has been loaded.

Comment: thanks for your proposition but it still doesn't work

Comment: I pulled this code from a page I've used it in. And just tested to make sure. Are you seeing any errors in the developer tools console? I know you didn't declare "popData" as "var popData" in the code you posted, wonder if you're getting a different js error.

Comment: i have no error in developper tool. i declare popData in page_load with: Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript
When i click, i see the popup reloaded and at the second time it closes. thanks

Comment: I meant in your code that you posted, you wrote `"popData = '" + checkedValue ...` instead of `var popData`. I understand what you're saying about the dialog, but I also know for a fact that you can close the dialog in a button click handler using the code I posted for you, because it's code I've used in an application, and I just tested it again. Good luck.

Comment: i added var before popData but doesn't change anything.
doesn't it come from the call of my popup?
Do you have a complete exemple for opening and retrieve value from popup like i use here?
thanks

Comment: Hope that helps